# How to Mock AWS::Transfer::TransferManager class using gmock?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, googlemock, aws-sdk-cpp

I am using AWS C++ SDK to download/upload files on AWS using `AWS::Transfer::TransferManager`. I want to unit test client class which makes uses of `TransferManager` and It requires to mock `TransferManager`. The AWS `TransferManager` class is concrete class, not an abstract class. How do I mock it?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64964355/1076113) describing a technique called hi-perf dependency injection.

Basically it allows you to define dependency injection of non-virtual class at compile time (and not at runtime, as with regular depencendy injection) using templates. Downside is that you'll have to have it in the header file.